# Insert span in contentEditable with document.execCommand('insertHTML',

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm working on a rich content editor. Configuration is set to adding a `<p>` tag as paragraph separator:

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, "p");
```

I have to insert special `<span contenteditable='false'>` sections:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "<span contenteditable='false'>...</span>");
```

**Insertions are not done as expected.**

I expect :

```
<p>something <span>...</span></p>
```

I got :

```
<p>something </p>
<span>...</span>
```

I can't figure out why the `span` tag is not inserted in the `p` tag. Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823691/insert-an-html-element-in-a-contenteditable-element

Comment: Hi, never heard of execCommand but when I searched MDN, they say it's obsolete see [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). Why aren't you using jQuery or normal js DOM methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`execCommand` has a history of inconsistency and bugginess across different browsers. Nowadays, `execCommand` is obsolete:

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some
>   browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any
>   time. Try to avoid using it.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

I suggest you to read this page on best alternatives : https://medium.com/@jitubutwal144/three-different-ways-to-build-inline-content-editor-using-javascrpit-d58c2edac9cb